# Layout of Activity page is broken on mobile web after achieving a new badge

Tags: bug, design, badges, mobile-web

When you receive a new badge, there is a dialog congratulating you on achieving a new badge. However, when dismissing the dialog, the layout is broken.

It shows the reputation graph (which isn't available in the mobile web) in front of the total reputation.

It shows like this:

> [image: broken]

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: I know it's old one, but we've done some updates for user profile so I'd appreciate if someone could double check if it's fixed.

Comment: Will you get me a badge then? ;)

Comment: [that's](http://printables-for-kids.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Badge-04.png) the only one i can give you ;p

Comment: I would love to have that badge... a mod for a year here? Where can I sign up? :) @Paweł

Comment: I'm removing the [status-review] tag because we've changed the layout of the mobile user page significantly since this issue was raised.

Comment: @Slate so better close this as "Can no longer be reproduced" to indicate this. (I cast the first vote)